# Is there a way to divide an image into multiple image without canvas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, image

I am currently working on a project that lets the user place in an image
And then cut the image into multiple parts to place it in individual cells in
an Excel file. I've looked up other answers to the same question before, but all seem to be using canvas.
I am quite in a dilemma since I have to cut the images into pieces without displaying anything on my screen browser.

Comment: How do you relate JavaScript to Excel here?

Comment: Take a look at the last example here: https://webcodingcenter.com/css/Background

Comment: Given the [tag:Node.js] tag, have you considered [`canvas`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)?

Comment: @ChongLipPhang Im currently using Exceljs to write data into the excel file. My goal was to create a heatmap to the canvas and adding the images over as background

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have considered using canvas as well. However, I cannot exactly show canvas on the main browser due to certain requirements I cannot control. Is it possible to use canvas and its properties without showing it on screen?

Comment: @ShuaSharp - See the link above in my comment.